# iOS: how to detect an Ipad is put in a special frame

Tags: ios, detection, sensors

I have programmed an Ipad application that has a behaviour that I would like to change if I put it in a wooden frame (any other material could be added). To simplify things, the background should change whenever is inside this frame, and there must be no tap-touch interaction, just putting the Ipad inside the frame.

Of course, we could program am specific gesture on the screen, like double tapping or swiping but it is not the searched solution.
Another thought has been to detect the lack of movement for a certain amount of time, but that would not assure that iPad is inside the frame.

I have thought about interacting with magnets (thinking about smartcovers) and the sleep sensor in the right side of the Ipad, but I don't know how to do it. 
I cannot see any other useful sensor.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Bluetooth? You could have a case / frame with an integrated iBeacon or similar that is only activated when an iPad is in contact with the frame. Would probably fail with multiple framed iPads in close proximity.

Comment: iBeacons does seem like the perfect solution to these, but you'd only really be able to detect proximity that close when the app is running in the foreground. Multiple iPads / cases *shouldn't* be an issue, I don't think.

Comment: Please give us some more specifics on the use case. Does the detecting only affect one app? Is it running in foreground? Is low power consumption on the iPad an issue? Can there be components to be installed in the frame?

Comment: Thx for your answers/questions. It would be a single app that does not run in foreground, low power consumption is not an issue, and it is possible to install components in the frame if there are not too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of accelerometer and the camera seems like an idea worth trying out:

Scan the accelerometer data to detect a spike followed by a flat line (= putting the iPad into the frame, then resting).

After detecting the motion event, use the back camera (maybe combined with the flash) to detect a pattern image fixed inside of the frame for this purpose. It might be necessary to put the pattern into a little hole to create at least a blurry image.

The second step is there to distinguish the frame from any other surface the iPad might be placed upon.